why does my VSCode exit with code 127 when trying to compile a C file using gcc?
I'm trying to compile a C file using gcc. I'm in the right directory and all the files included in the C file i'm trying to compile is in the same directory. I can compile other files but I can't compile files that are using this ADT Matrix. the files I have in this directory
#include <stdio.h>
#include "matrix.c"
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int n,i,j,k,l;
    int count;
    Matrix m;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    readMatrix(&m, n, n);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (j=0; j<n; j++){
            if (ELMT(m,i,j)==0){
                continue;
            } else 
                for (k=i+1; k<n; k++){
                    //printf("i = %d, j = %d, k = %d\n", i, j, k);
                    //printf("ELMT(k,j) = %d\n",ELMT(m,k,j));
                    if (ELMT(m,k,j)!=0){
                        count += ELMT(m,k,j);
                    }
                }
                for (k=i-1; k>=0; k--){
                    //printf("i = %d, j = %d, k = %d\n", i, j, k);
                    //printf("ELMT(k,j) = %d\n",ELMT(m,k,j));
                    if (ELMT(m,k,j)!=0){
                        count += ELMT(m,k,j);
                    }
                }
                for (k=j+1; k<n; k++){
                    //printf("i = %d, j = %d, k = %d\n", i, j, k);
                    //printf("ELMT(i,k = %d\n", ELMT(m,i,k));
                    if (ELMT(m,i,k)!=0){
                        count += ELMT(m,i,k);
                    }
                }
                for (k=j-1; k>=0; k--){
                    //printf("i = %d, j = %d, k = %d\n", i, j, k);
                    //printf("ELMT(i,k = %d\n", ELMT(m,i,k));
                    if (ELMT(m,i,k)!=0){
                        count += ELMT(m,i,k);
                    }
                }
                
        }
    }

    int mod = 1000000007;
    count = count % mod;
    printf("%d\n", count);
    //printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}


this is kekacauan.c
this is the command i used. when i hover the red circle it says that it tried to run for ... miliseconds and then exited with code 127
I was expecting the code to run as usual, but it exited with code 127.

} else is suspicious.  Did you want } else { ... }?  Save time, enable all warnings. "warning: this 'else' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]"

Welcome to SO. You forgot to include the exact error message in your question. Also the command you are using to build your code is missing. Please edit your question to include that information.

Including .c files is a clear indication of bad design, don't do that. Write .h files with their own corresponding .c file.

I am with chux. Cleaning up your indentation clearly shows that several loops are unconditional while your original indentation misleadingly suggests the opposite. Please confirm that you intend them to be unconditional (i.e. not affect by the ìf` which makes the first in the row coniditional). Also please provide a [mre]. As far as I can tell the shown code at least lacks details on the contents of matrix.c (i.e. I am also with Lundin).
